# Any reason to version control Elm's `build-artifacts`?

Tags: elm

Is there any reason to keep `elm-stuff/build-artifacts` under version control? I was thinking I'd add it to my `.gitignore`, since it seems to change every time my `.elm` file changes.

([This project](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/8f35779cefbabdca21cfc4cda55abb1290d59fd9/Elm.gitignore) ignores the whole `elm-stuff` folder, but that seems wrong to me because `exact-dependencies.json` is in there.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The content of `elm-stuff` gets generated from your source code so it's generally safe to ignore it's content.

For your question about committing `exact-dependencies.json` or not I think you should look at what the [Rust community suggests for their equivalent `cargo.lock`](http://doc.crates.io/faq.html#why-do-binaries-have-cargolock-in-version-control-but-not-libraries).

If you're building an application and if you care about deterministic builds then it's better to commit it. If you are writing a library it's better to leave dependency resolution to the application that is using the library.

Note that Elm enforces semantic versioning so you can have the guarantee that a package upgrade is not going to break your build. That doesn't prevent change in the behaviour, that's why if you want deterministic builds you should commit your `exact-dependencies.json`.